# PHP - LDAP - Fetching users' groups GUID, not name

Tags: php, ldap, guid

I am in the process of building a website for a company I work for. I would like to run some of it off the LDAP server that's already in use. Right now I have it linked for logging in and out, not much of an issue.

My next step, which has seemed to become more of a delay, is user groups and permissions. I would like to be able to get the groups a user is member of. Normally, this will just return the full string of the group, but I would prefer to have the GUID.

I know I can take the strings and query the server, then obtain the group GUID. This just seems to be more processing for the server.

I'd like to have this for logging in the database. If the name changes, the list of users don't. It would cause too many issues and store too much in the database if I went based off the full string rather than the GUID.

My other idea/option would be to search and cache all the GUIDs in a table, updating the names if they change. This way I'm not querying the LDAP server a munch for what I need, and can manage it all inside the same server. The servers are in the same network, but it's always fastest when running locally.

**TL;DR**
Is there a way I can query the LDAP server and get the list of groups a user is in, returning the group GUID rather than its full name.

I'm still new to working with LDAP too, in case I'm missing anything.

Comment: Sorry if i am completely off topic, but it seem to be a basic option of ldap_search ?
What happens if you try : 
    ldap_search ( $link_identifier , $base_dn , $filter, ["guid"]);

Comment: Searching for users works. The problem is it never returns the GUID of the groups they're a member of. Instead it returns the full string containing the domain controller(s), organizational unit(s), and common name. To save space, and to retain settings in the event a group name is change,d I'd prefer to go off the GUID.

Comment: The name I'm thinking of for the full string is distinguished name, for reference.

Comment: I've settled with caching the list of groups and their GUIDs into a sql table. This way I can combine the data with other queries if ever needed, and I won't be spamming queries to the LDAP servers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's overkill to make a local replication, openldap can carry out 22,000 queries / second or 4,800 update / second and can contain up to 150 million entries (Year 2006 benchmark).

It's the job of the LDAP to do this, and it does it generally well.
Your local replication just involve latency when there is a user/group change, can be source of errors, while it does not bring significant improve.

Comment: We don't do too many group changes. I set up a cron task to update them every hour. Worse case scenario, I set the function to reverse lookup to accept a force requery parameter to bypass the cache if needed.

The main reason being most users may have anywhere from 5 to 20 groups assigned. When checking them on almost every page request, it can add up fairly quickly. Add in around 300 locations, 20 directors, and other employees. Not every location will be on simultaneously, but I don't want to bog down the LDAP server with this when it's already doing queries for other services.